# How to set a specific local branch to track a specific upstream branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, branching-and-merging

I have a repo that is forked, call this myFork. 
The repo that I forked from, call it upstream.

I set up the upstream repo using this:
https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/configuring-a-remote-for-a-fork

On myFork, I have 2 branches: `master` and `myDevelop`. 
For `master`, it is used to track changes to `upstream/master`. 
How do I setup so that `myDevelop` to track `upstream/develop` only?

To expand the question further, how do I:

- set xyz branch on `myFork` to set abc branch on `upstream`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Comment: Answer already provided at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch

Answer (score -1):

You can run `git branch -vv` to show up which remote branch a local branch is tracking.

If you want to base your work on an upstream branch that already exists at the remote, you need to run `git fetch` to retrieve it first.

Then `git checkout abc` to select the branch.

Finally, run `git branch -u origin/xyz` from abc branch to start tracking xyz branch.